# How to get data from $http on the page?

Tags: angularjs

I am writing a small test page that retrieves some data from a RESTful API I have previously written.

I can successfully retrieve this data from Angular, but I can't seem to find a way to display this data on the page. I am trying to loop over the list of results and print it in a `table`.

This is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS</title>
        
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf8" >
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap.css">
        
        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.js"></script>
        
        <script type="application/javascript" src="./js/URLSet.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="./js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="MyApp">
        <div ng-controller="URLSetDAO as dao">
            <button class="btn" ng-click="dao.list()">List</button>
            <table class="table" ng-init="urlsets = dao.list()">
                <td ng-repeat="urlset in urlsets">
                    <tr>
                        {{ urlset.pk }}
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        {{ urlset.user }}
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        {{ urlset.title }}
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        {{ urlset.views}}
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        {{ urlset.type }}
                    </tr>
                </td>
            </table>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the `app.js`:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['URLSet']);
})();
```

And this is the `URLSet.js`:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('URLSet', []);
    
    app.controller('URLSetDAO', ['$http', function($http){
        var ip = "http://localhost:8000";
        var store = this;
        
        this.list = function() {
            return $http({method: 'GET', url: ip + '/urlsets/'})
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                
                });
        };
        
        this.read = function(id) {
            $http({method: 'GET', url: ip + '/urlsets/' + id})
                ...
        };
        
        this.create = function(obj) {
            $http({method: 'POST', url: ip + '/urlsets/'})
                ...
        };
        
        this.update = function(id, obj) {
            $http({method: 'PUT', url: ip + '/urlsets/' + id})
                ...
        };
        
        this.remove = function(id) {
            $http({method: 'DELETE', url: ip + '/urlsets/' + id})
                ...
        };
  }]);
})();
```

I understand that Promises work similarly to callbacks, so it's asynchronous. So how am I able to display this data, if `ng-init` will not wait for the function to finish?

**EDIT:**

Besides the fact that I inverted the `tr` and `td` tags (thanks to [satish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/329845/satish) for suggesting Plunker, which pointed me this error), making the table render invisible (so I would never see the results on the page), I also injected `$scope` into my controller.

It is like this now:

```
...
app.controller('URLSetDAO', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope){
        var ip = "http://localhost:8000";
        var store = this;
        
        this.list = function() {
            $http({method: 'GET', url: ip + '/urlsets/'})
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.urlsets = data;
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                
                });
        };
...
```

And index.html:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
        <div ng-controller="URLSetDAO as dao">
            <button class="btn" ng-click="dao.list()">List</button>
            <table class="table" ng-init="dao.list()">
                <tr ng-repeat="urlset in urlsets">
                    <td>
                        {{ urlset.pk }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ urlset.user }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ urlset.title }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ urlset.views}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ urlset.type }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>      
    </body>
```

Comment: Can you show a plunker for the same. We can correct the implementation

Comment: @satish Oh wow without your comment, I would have never seen it. I inverted the `td` and `tr` tags. Plunker pointed that error to me. This code is working, it just wasn't being rendered correctly. I was thinking it's very weird it wouldn't work although I was following everything correctly. Thanks for this and sorry about this dumb mistake.

Comment: Can you update the question and close it as an answer . It will help others get the answer correctly . Thanks

Comment: How can I close it? Should I flag it?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to drop the `ng-init` and do that in your controller instead:

For example:

```
app.controller('URLSetDAO', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope){
    var ip = "http://localhost:8000";
    var store = this;

    this.list = function() {
        return $http({method: 'GET', url: ip + '/urlsets/'})
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            });
    };

    this.list().success(data) {
      $scope.urlsets = data;
    });

    ...

});
```

Hope this helps.